# Permutation and combination Number of Bits Problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, logic, permutations, combinations

how many bit strings of length eight either start with a '1' bit or end with the two bits '00'?
I got the answer 128 by using the "exclusive or" approach i.e. for bit strings starting with '1':  There is one way to choose the first bit, 2^5 ways to choose the succeeding 5 bits and 3 ways to choose the last 2 bits= 3*2^5
and for bits ending with '00': There is one way to choose the  first and last two bits and 2^5 ways to choose the remaining bits= 2^5
Therefore answer will be= 3*2^5+2^5=128.

Comment: Assuming you meant the non-exclusive or:  There are $2^7$ that begin with $1$.  There are $2^6$ that end in $00$.  There are $2^5$ that BOTH begin with $1$ and end in $00$.  Thus the answer is $2^7+2^6-2^5=160$.  Assuming you meant the exclusive or:  we then have to subtract $2^5$ again, now getting your $128$.  So...did you mean the exclusive or?  That should be specified.

Comment: @lulu I noticed that you put you answerS as comments. Why? (just curious)

Comment: Can you add how you got your answer of $128$? We'll be able to help you better if we can see how you got your answer.

Comment: @adhg  That was hardly an answer...I was just pointing out that the question was ambiguous and that (what I imagine to be) the standard reading would yield a different answer but that a (somewhat) non-standard reading would give the "right" answer.  I was asking the OP for clarification.

Comment: I think "Either" in this question signify 'Exclusive or' itself and there is no need to specify it.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $$n(A\cup B)=n(A)+n(B)-n(A\cap B)$$
where $A$ is the set of $8$ length bit strings starting with $1,B$ is the set of $8$ length bit strings ending in $00$.

$n(A)=2^7$, because the remaining last $7$ bits can be $0,1$.

$n(B)=2^6$, because the remaining first $4$ bits can be $0,1$.

$n(A\cap B)$ is the number of $8$ length bit strings which both start with $1$ and end in $00$. Thus, there are $5$ bits which we can vary, resulting in $n(A\cap B)=2^5$.

The required answer is $2^7+2^6-2^5=128+64-32=160$.